# Code For Jquery AM PM Picker

Tags: jquery, datetime

I am familier with the Jquery date picker ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/premseoul/myvaf/2/)). But I want to create an AM/PM picker based on Jquery so when the user clicks on the button it will show TIME like:(12:56:AM), (01:12:PM).  How can I implement that functionality? Can anyone help me with links/jsFiddle/etc.

Comment: Consider using an alternative: [Anytime date picker](http://www.ama3.com/anytime/).

Answer (score 0):

This one is my personal favorite:

http://pttimeselect.sourceforge.net/example/index.html

Answer (score 0):

As Vic said, [Any+Time(TM)](http://www.ama3.com/anytime/) should meet your needs nicely.  The time picker appears when you click on the field, or there are some tips for attaching it to a button.  It supports countless formats, including date+time combined.  If you have any problems, simply request help using the Contact link on the website.